# Vue-Native checkbox change value

Tags: vue.js, vue-native

I want to be able to change the value of a checkbox by clicking on it. `recentContacts` are loading just fine, and specifying initial checked values in the computed function works well. The `:on-press` seems to change the value but does not reflect in the UI.

Please Help

## Template

```
<nb-list>
    <nb-list-item v-for="contact in recentContacts" v-bind:key="contact.uid">
       <nb-checkbox :on-press="() => contact.checked =! contact.checked" :checked="contact.checked"></nb-checkbox>
       <nb-text>{{contact.firstName}} {{contact.lastName}}</nb-text>
    </nb-list-item>
</nb-list>
```

## Code

```
export default {
   computed: {
        recentContacts() {
            return store.state.admin.userData.recentContacts.map(rc => {
                rc.checked = false;
                return rc;
            });
        }
    },
}
```

EDIT:
I am guessing because VUEX is imutable. I've got this to work by having `recentContacts` inside of the `data` attribute instead of `computed` just not how I want to do things.

Comment: you need to change space location `contact.checked = !contact.checked`

Comment: Is it not because of VUEX's immutability?

Comment: have you tried my suggestion ?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki yes, I also tried `contact.checked = true` and no luck

Comment: I console log recentContacts and it shows the data has indeed changed; however, Its just not updating in the checkbox

Comment: what happens when you try : `:checked=true` !!

Comment: adding `:checked=true` works Furthermore, changing the `rc.checked = true` also works. I just can't get it to change with `:on-press`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191794/discussion-between-carlos-pliego-and-ahmad-mobaraki).

Comment: How about `:on-press="contact.checked = !contact.checked"` without an arrow function?

Comment: https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/adding-getters-setters-computed-properties